# Getting invalid entry size ZipException while reading excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I was trying to read an **Confidential labeled** excel file from Onedrive using Apache POI.

Please find my code snippet below:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xlsx"))
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis)
```

The code was working fine , but suddenly the second line is giving invalid entry size exception.

I have tried to replace the Apache POI jar files, but still it is not working.

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:103)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324) 
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
at ReadingData.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:31) 
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 1053 bytes
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:399) 
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:198))
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFileSThresholdInputStream.read(ZipsecureFile.java:228) 
at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:186)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySources FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132) 
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56) 
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.zipPackage <init>(ZipPackage.java:109)
4 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is OK? Can you open it with a local Excel installation?

Comment: Yes I can open the excel without any error in Excel app

Comment: Please provide full stack trace in your question. And please tell us what Apache POI version used.

Comment: I am using Apache poi 3.17

Comment: What happens when you copy that file elsewhere, say `%TMP%` and then try to open it with POI?

Comment: You seems to have a mix of Apache POI versions in class path while runing. That is not supported. You get `... at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFileSThresholdInputStream.read(ZipsecureFile.java:228) ...`: But code line 228 is *not* in `read` method of `org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFileSThresholdInputStream` in [REL_3_17_FINAL](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/util/ZipSecureFile.java?view=markup#l209). Please use only one Apache POI version.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes I had a mix of Apache POI versions. I removed the older version. But still it was not working. I then saved a copy of that excel in my local. Then I was able to read the excel. Seems like some encryption was there in the OneDrive excel